# How to resolve Get Google Play services error

Tags: google-play-store, lg

I have an LG H440 (Spirit) and I have restored it to factory settings because it was in a "bootloop".

Upon restarting the device there is an error message that is titled "Get Google Play services" the body of the text then says "Hangouts won't run without Google Play services,which are missing from your phone".

The phone still reboots from time to time when I open a couple apps and my playstore still will not open. I'm not an advanced user and my attempts of rooting the phone have failed mostly because the phone restarts before the process is complete.

Please advise on a resolution.

Answer (score 8):

Simply click this link below it will redirect you to "google play services" in play store. There can be options:

1. To update(you need to update in this case), or
2. To deactive(nothing needed, it is already up-to-date).

Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&showAllReviews=true

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

After factory reset the core Google Play Services application needs to be updated, 
which is most probably you are getting the "Google Play Services missing error"

Try this to resolve the problem:

- Go to Settings → Applications → Google Play Services → Clear cache/data.
- Go to Settings → Applications → Google play store → Clear cache/data.
- Go to Settings → Applications → Google Services Framework → Clear cache
  /data.

The next step needs an active internet connection..

- Now open any Google application (e.g Gmail, Google+ or Google maps) this prompts to update Google Play Services and be sure to update.
- You also need to update Google playstore

Reboot device.

Alternatively if you can't update with your device, then I suggest you get the .apk file from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/) or webinterface (via [apkleecher.com](http://www.apkleecher.com) / [evozi.com)](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) , and install it.